# One swap function to be used by 2 different structs

Tags: c

I wonder if it is possible for 1 function such as swap() to be used in two different structs to swap them?
So for example,

```
typedef struct{
char a;
}one;

typedef struct{
int c;
}two;

swap(??,??){
// code to swap 2 elements
}

one arr[8];
arr[1].a='a';
arr[2].a='b';

two brr[8];
brr[1].c = 11;
brr[2].c = 12;
```

So, based on that, is it possible for swap function to be able to swap the elements in structs? E.g is it possible to use:
1. swap(arr[1],arr[2]);
2. swap(brr[1],brr[2]);

From my understanding, such thing cannot be done since the data type for both struct (and also its element) are different. I've been wondering of making a modular function for one my project so help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you can define macro for this

Comment: Using C and as you've written it, no. It's not possible without writing some really ugly code. However, you might want to investigate unions.

Comment: macro, or change it to `swap(foo, bar, size)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need a generic function that takes memory addresses to swap instead:

```
void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size)
{
    void *tmp = malloc(size);
    // you should make sure the memory allocation was successful

    memcpy(tmp, a, size);
    memcpy(a, b, size);
    memcpy(b, tmp, size);

    free(tmp);
}
```

Instead of the elements, you pass in their addresses:

```
swap(&arr[1], &arr[2], sizeof(one));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a macro, not a function. I've tested it on GCC and Clang on Linux x86-64 with -O1 optimisations. It looks the compilers are smart enough to get rid of malloc, memcpy and free for small structs. This code should compile to something smaller than a proper call to a function.

```
#define swap(a, i1, i2)\
{\
    size_t size = sizeof(a[i1]);\
    void *tmp_elm = malloc(size);\
    memcpy(tmp_elm, &a[i1],  size);\
    memcpy(&a[i1],  &a[i2],  size);\
    memcpy(&a[i2],  tmp_elm, size);\
    free(tmp_elm);\
}
```

The example of use:

```
one arr[8];
two brr[8];
/* Set these two arrays. */
swap(arr, 1, 2);
swap(brr, 1, 2);
```